# "Bereaved" vs. "bereft"

Tags: word-choice, past-participles, ed-vs-t

I saw the sentence below, and I think it would sound better after changing "bereaved" to "bereft":

> Having lost his father in early childhood, he was **bereaved** of his love and affection.

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary definitions of *bereaved* and *bereft* are:

> bereaved (adjective): having lost a relative or close friend who has
>   recently died
>
> bereft (adjective): **bereft of something** completely lacking something;
>   having lost something

Comment: As suggested by user: @pablopaul “*bereaved is also the correct form to use when referring to the loss of cherished characteristics of the deceased.”*

Comment: @pablopaul With a supporting reference, that would be the correct answer.

Comment: Interesting question. To me, *bereaved* suggested he didn't receive a father's love and affection, and *bereft* suggests he has none to give others. The choice changes the antecedent of the pronoun *his*.

Comment: Dear user159691, Edwin Ashworth, and Phil Sweet, thank you for your replying.
I can understand it.

Answer (score 2):

The distinction may become clearer if the sentence is rephrased as,"Having been bereaved in early childhood, he remained bereft of fatherly love and affection.

Comment: Dear Anand Bapat thank you for your replying.
Thank you for your rephrased sentence.
I can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Using "bereft" should be better. As the focus of this sentence is the lost of his father's love and affection but not his dad.

Comment: Dear SunShine Wong thank you for your replying.
>Using "bereft" should be better.
I think so too. Thank you very much.